# Why does calling root.destroy still not continue my loop?

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, while-loop, program-entry-point

I am creating a board game, and i am using Tkinter for the GUI interface. I created the main loop like this:

```
while gameOn == True: #The loop
    main_game_AI() #This is the actual game
    root.mainloop() #This puts together the window.
    root.destroy()  #This closes the mainloop so the loop can continue.
```

But when i ran it, the loop only iterated one time. Is there something wrong with the order of the functions??

Comment: move `root.destroy()`  outside your loop.

Comment: What im trying to do, is to exit the root.mainloop() so that i can continue the game loop. I just want it to do the game loop one time, while showing the window. Then i exit it very quickly, and repeat.

Comment: When i try it, it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

`root.mainloop()` won't return until the root window has been destroyed, or until you call `root.quit()`. Therefore, yoru call to `root.destroy()` won't be called until the user quits your program.

Comment: Yes, but when i change it to quit, it still does not work.

Comment: If i try putting the root.quit() before, it still does not work either.